# Log4j Custom adapter without additivity

Tags: java, log4j, duplicates

following Case: I have programmed a custom adapter to support log output redirect in two textareas (overwrite of the  protected void append(LoggingEvent event) method with textArea.setText()).

The problem now is that log 4j fileAppender creates duplicate log outputs because of console and statusMessageAdapter. When i remove one of them only one log is added but the redirect to the textareas doesnt work anymore.
When i turn additivity for package foo.bar off, the textarea isnt filled anymore.

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG,console,textarea,stdLog,errorLog
log4j.additivity.rootLogger=false

log4j.appender.console = org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.console.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
 log4j.appender.console.Threshold=INFO

#textarea appender
log4j.appender.textarea = foo.bar.StatusMessageAppender
log4j.appender.textarea.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.textarea.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
log4j.appender.textarea.Threshold=INFO

#file appender
log4j.appender.stdLog=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.stdLog.DatePattern = '.'yyyy-MM-ww
log4j.appender.stdLog.File = log/log.txt
log4j.appender.stdLog.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdLog.layout.ConversionPattern = [%d{ISO8601}]%5p%6.6r[%t]%x(%F:%L) - %m%n
log4j.appender.stdLog.Threshold=DEBUG

  #file appender
 log4j.appender.errorLog = org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
 log4j.appender.errorLog.DatePattern = '.'yyyy-MM-ww
 log4j.appender.errorLog.File = log/errorlog.txt
 log4j.appender.errorLog.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
 log4j.appender.errorLog.layout.ConversionPattern = [%d{ISO8601}]%5p%6.6r[%t]%x(%F:%L) - %m%n
 log4j.appender.errorLog.Threshold=ERROR

 #Specific log levels
 log4j.category.foo.bar= TRACE
 log4j.category.foo.bar.utils= INFO
 #log4j.additivity.foo.bar = false
```

Comment: Are you sure you are actually logging twice? I can't reproduce the described behavior with your configuration

Comment: unfortunaly, yes. i have to turn additivity on, otherwise no output is transferred in the textareas

Comment: Post the log output and the minimal code we can run